# Correct way to handle foreign keys using Laravel migrations?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I'm a newbie to laravel and migrations, and I can't seem to figure out the correct way to set up a foreign key.

```
Schema::create('sights', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('contact_id');
        $table->integer('media_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('sights', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');
        $table->foreign('media_id')->references('sight_id')->on('sightMedia');
    });
```

If it's not clear, "contact_id" is a foreign key that's supposed to reference the column "id" in the table called "contacts",
and "media_id" references the column "sight_id" in the intermediary table "sightMedia".

The error it gives me when I try to migrate is the following:

[image: error screenshot]

EDIT: This is the users table, it's second in the line of migrations so I suppose that's where the migrations stop and report an error.

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('firstName');
        $table->string('lastName');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('facebook');
        $table->integer('score_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->foreign('score_id')->references('id')->on('scores');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So in short: If you want to assign a foreign key from some table, that table where the foreign key comes from, must be created before assigning the key in some other table. And always add ->unsigned(); to foreign key ids

Comment: @Jesse Can you show us migration with `users_role_id_foreign`?

Comment: @lewis4u Sorry, could I ask you to clarify? Do you mean that I should first create a migration for the referencing table (sights), and then for the table that is referenced (contacts)? As I said, I'm new to migrations so I'm still quite unclear on what they're for and what they do, so I had no idea the order of them mattered, but thank you for the help!

Comment: @skido I've edited my post to include the users table :)

Comment: @Jesse yes the order which your migrations take place matters....when you are creating a migration with a foreign key....that foreign key and table must exist before you assign it...

Comment: @lewis4u Thanks for the help! I'll give that a try right now :)